# Custom UIMenuController issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I have a UITable and a UITextView on a View Controller. I want to have a custom UIMenuController with options 'Copy' and 'Info' when I longpress the tableviewcell and I want to have the default UIMenuController on longpress of UITextView.

I searched for a solution and now I am able to create a custom UIMenuItem 'Info'. But, when I long press the UITextView I see that 'Info' is appended as well.

**How can I set custom UIMenuController only for the UITableView and not for UITextView? I want the default options alone in the UITextView.**

Answer (score 0):

Bit late here, 
 I also had same issue where the default UIMenuController default items get added to custom one as its a shared instance control across the application. 
   You should subclass your UITextView and add method:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
      if ( action== @selector(yourMethodInfo:)) {
                    return NO; }

                     return YES;

    }
```

Also don't used sharedInstance of UIMenuController and create a separate object for your Custom TextView subclass and use that. After you invoke the UIMenuController from your UITableView you should  do 
   `[menuController setMenuItems:nil];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:NO]; [menuController update]; menuController= nil;`
After a menu item is selected on your selector method.

If someone needs more reference let me know, I can provide more explanations .

Answer (score 0):

Your question:

> How can I set custom UIMenuController only for the UITableView and not for UITextView? I want the default options alone in the UITextView.

**The answer is: You can't.**

**Reason:** You can only get the UIMenuController Instance by invoking class method like this:`[UIMenuController sharedMenuController]`. See Apple's documentation:[UIMenuController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html)

**How to solve the issue:**

**Set your custom UIMenuItems nil When shared UIMenuController will hide**.

Example code:

```
-(void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    //other stuff code...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleMenuWillShowNotification:) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)handleMenuWillShowNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleMenuWillHideNotification:) name:UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)handleMenuWillHideNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification object:nil];
    UIMenuController *menuController = notification.object;
    [menuController setMenuItems:nil];
}
```